# "Same as Shipping" check box isn't working. My code is attached, what am I missing? {JavaScript code only; html posted for reference}

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to copy all data from a 'shipping' address over to the 'billing' address section. I've provided all of my code, but for some reason nothing is copying over when the check box `useShip` is selected. The HTML code is provided for any reference, however I'm working entirely in javascript on this.

Please let me know what I've done wrong. Any advice or answer would be greatly appreciated!

Javascript:

```
"use strict";

let useShip = document.getElementById("useShip");
let lastnameBill = document.getElementById("lastnameBill");
let lastnameShip = document.getElementById("lastnameShip");

useShip.addEventListener("change", copyShippingToBilling);

function copyShippingToBilling() {
      let useShip = document.getElementById("useShip").checked;
      if (useShip.checked == true) {
            let firstnameBill = document.getElementById("firstnameBill");
            let firstnameShip = document.getElementById("firstnameShip");
            firstnameBill.value = firstnameShip.value;

            let lastnameBill = document.getElementById("lastnameBill");
            let lastnameShip = document.getElementById("lastnameShip");
            lastnameBill.value = lastnameShip.value;

            let address1Bill = document.getElementById("address1Bill");
            let address1Ship = document.getElementById("address1Ship");
            address1Bill.value = address1Ship.value;

            let address2Bill = document.getElementById("address2Bill");
            let address2Ship = document.getElementById("address2Ship");
            address2Bill.value = address2Ship.value;

            let cityBill = document.getElementById("cityBill");
            let cityShip = document.getElementById("cityShip");
            cityBill.value = cityShip.value;

            let countryBill = document.getElementById("countryBill");
            let countryShip = document.getElementById("countryShip");
            countryBill.value = countryShip.value;

            let codeBill = document.getElementById("codeBill");
            let codeShip = document.getElementById("codeShip");
            codeBill.value = codeShip.value;

            let stateBill = document.getElementById("stateBill");
            let stateShip = document.getElementById("stateShip");
            stateBill.selectedIndex === ShippingToBilling.selectedIndex;
      }
}

let formElements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
let fieldCount = formElements.length;
let errorBox = document.getElementById("errorBox");
for (let i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
      formElements[i].addEventListener('invalid', showValidationError);
}

function showValidationError(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      errorBox.textContent = "Complete all highlighted fields";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>HTML</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
   <script src="project06-03.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <h1>
      </h1>
   </header>

   <article>
      <h1>Checkout</h1>
      <form id="billShip" name="billShip" method="get" action="formsubmit.html">
         <section>
            <legend>Shipping Address</legend>
            <fieldset id="shipping">
               
               <p><span>*</span> &mdash; Required Field</p>
               <label for="firstnameShip">First Name <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="firstnameShip" name="firstnameShip" />
               
               <label for="lastnameShip">Last Name <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="lastnameShip" name="lastnameShip"  />
               
               <label for="address1Ship">Address Line 1 <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="address1Ship" name="address1Ship"   />
               
               <label for="address2Ship">Address Line 2 <span>&nbsp;</span></label>
               <input type="text" id="address2Ship" name="address2Ship"   />
               
               <label for="cityShip">City <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="cityShip" name="cityShip"   />   
               
               <label for="stateShip">State <span>*</span></label>
               <select id="stateShip" name="stateShip">
                  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                  <option value="CA">California</option>
                  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                  <option value="NY">New York</option>
                  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
               </select>                               

               <label for="countryShip">Country <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="countryShip" name="countryShip" value="United States" />  
 
               <label for="codeShip">Postal Code <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="codeShip" name="codeShip" />                
            </fieldset>
         </section>
         
         <section>
            <legend>Billing Address</legend>
            <fieldset id="billing">
               
               <input type="checkbox" name="useShip" id="useShip" />
               <label id="cbLabel" for="useShip">Same as Shipping Address</label>
               
               <label for="firstnameBill">First Name <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="firstnameBill" name="firstnameBill"   />
               
               <label for="lastnameBill">Last Name <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="lastnameBill" name="lastnameBill"   />
               
               <label for="address1Bill">Address Line 1 <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="address1Bill" name="address1Bill" />
               
               <label for="address2Bill">Address Line 2 <span>&nbsp;</span></label>
               <input type="text" id="address2Bill" name="address2Bill"   />
               
               <label for="cityBill">City <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="cityBill" name="cityBill"/>   
               
               <label for="stateBill">State <span>*</span></label>
               <select id="stateBill" name="stateBill">
                  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                  <option value="CA">California</option>
                  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                  <option value="NY">New York</option>
                  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
               </select>                               

               <label for="countryBill">Country <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="countryBill" name="countryBill" value="United States"  />  
 
               <label for="codeBill">Postal Code <span>*</span></label>
               <input type="text" required id="codeBill" name="codeBill" />                
            </fieldset>
         </section>
         
         <p id="errorBox"></p>
         <input type="submit" value="Next" />      
      </form>
   </article>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the line to `useShip.addEventListener("change", copyShippingToBilling);` however it didn't seems to fix the issue. I'm guessing I must have missed something deep in the code somewhere?

Comment: `let useShip = document.getElementById("useShip").checked;` and then `useShip.checked == true`. Think there are too many `.checked` here. `useShip` is going to be a boolean value and `useShip.checked` will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
useShip.addEventListener("click", copyShippingToBilling);
```

with:

```
useShip.addEventListener("change", copyShippingToBilling);
```

The reason is that checkboxes have "change" events instead of click events for change detection during events.

Comment: Okay, thanks Phuzi! That worked!!

However, I've noticed that my `selectIndex` isn't copying over to my other `selectIndex`. This is the code I have for that:

`stateBill.selectedIndex === ShippingToBilling.selectedIndex;`

 What am I missing?